# Question concerning Mumford's Abelian Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question concerning the following corollary in Mumford's Abelian Varieties:

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper morphism between noetherian schemes, let $Y$ be reduced. Then for all $p$ the following are equivalent:

1. $y\mapsto \text{dim}_{\kappa(y)}H^p(X_y,\mathcal{F}_y)$ is a constant function,
2. $\mathcal{R}^pf_*(\mathcal{F})$ is a locally free sheaf $\varepsilon$ on $Y$, and for all $y\in Y$, the natural map $\varepsilon\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}\kappa(y)\rightarrow H^p(X_y. \mathcal{F}_y)$ is an isomorphism.

Firstawall, I don't understand the notation in 2.. Is "$\kappa(y)$" the constant sheaf associated to $\kappa(y)$ and is "$H^p(X_y. \mathcal{F}_y)$" also simply the constant sheaf associated to $H^p(X_y. \mathcal{F}_y)$?

Secondly, where do I need the assumption that $\mathcal{R}^pf_*(\mathcal{F})$ is locally free when showing that "$2.\Rightarrow 1.$"?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: $\kappa(y)$ is structural sheaf on $y$. This notation suggest it is the skycraper sheaf $i_*\kappa(y)$ on $y$, or better, $\epsilon\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}\kappa(y)$ is the pullback $i^*\epsilon$ where $i:y\rightarrow Y$. Same with $H^p(X_y,\mathcal{F}_y)$. In any case, these should be considered as coherent sheaves on $y$ hence as $\kappa(y)$-vector spaces. For the second question, what happen if $\epsilon$ is supported on, say, a point ?

Comment: Thank you! You mean $\text{supp}(\mathcal{\varepsilon})=\{x\in Y; \varepsilon_x\neq 0\}=\{pt\}$? Well, then $\varepsilon$ is not locally free since the rank of $\varepsilon$ is then not defined...I think I need another hint...

Comment: Well, I had in mind the example of $i:X\rightarrow Y$ the closed immersion of a point. Then $R^pi_*\mathcal{O}_X=0$ for $p>0$ and is supported on $X$ for $p=0$. As you said, it is not locally free, but for all $y$ the natural map would be an isomorphism. That does not make $y\mapsto \dim_{\kappa(y)}H^p(X_y,(i_*\mathcal{O}_X)_y)$ a constant function.